# Excluding 0 results from being Conditionally Formatted

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I want to conditionally format a cell as one color for a result that is above 40% of another cell & exclude the 0 results from being formatted. I can achieve the 1st part with =(c301*.4) as the conditional formatting formula, but I am having a dickens of a time with excluding the 0 results being formatted; as you'll see in cell L300 of the picture below.

I have tried an AND formula =AND(L301*.4,L300>0) and while I get a TRUE result when in a cell, it does not change the conditional formatting when used there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you got the formula to work in a cell, conditional formatting will work for you.

It's important to note that I have had the most success when I want to have the same conditional formatting for a range of cells to begin simple and only create the conditional format for a single cell.  This ensures that the conditional format is looking at the correct cells when the range is applied.

It also appears that you are not using absolute references but relative references in the formula.  As it stands right now, the conditional format formula (if applied to L301) will look at itself and the **cell above**.  If that is not what you want, you can make the row and/or column absolute by adding `$` in front of the cell reference.

`=AND(L301*.4,L$300>0)` This new formula will (if applied to L301) look at itself and always row 300 of the selected column.  If the range was extended to L302 effectively the formula would transpose and read `=AND(L302*.4,L$300>0)` and if M301 was also added `=AND(M301*.4,M$300>0)`.

`=AND(L301*.4,$L300>0)` This new formula will (if applied to L301) look at itself and the row above in column L.  If this new formula was extended to L302, the formula would transpose to `=AND(L302*.4,$L301>0)`.  With cell M301, `=AND(M301*.4,$L300>0)`.

`=AND(L301*.4,$L$300>0)` This new formula will (if applied to L301) look at itself and always L300.  For cell L301, `=AND(L302*.4,$L$300>0)`.  Cell M301, `=AND(M301*.4,$L$300>0)`